# Get logged in user with - custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development, user-access

I am writing my own plugin and I am stuck quite early on. I am trying to get the ID of currently logged in user, via php script.
Something like this

```
add_action('init','do_stuff');
function do_stuff(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    // rest of my code here
}
```

However I am **always** getting the result 0.

I am aware that there are multiple similar questions, but literally no solutions worked so far. E.g.

[wp_get_current_user always returns 0](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30061/wp-get-current-user-always-returns-0)

[wp_get_current_user() function not working in Rest API callback function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/299836/wp-get-current-user-function-not-working-in-rest-api-callback-function/329992#329992)

[wp_get_current_user always returns 0 continued](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41292/wp-get-current-user-always-returns-0-continued)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `init` hook why don't you use the `wp_loaded` hook. This way, you're sure that everything is loaded

```
add_action('wp_loaded','do_stuff');
function do_stuff(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ($current_user->ID > 0) {
        // rest of your code here
        // $current_user->ID will give you the ID of the current user.
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the [User Contributed Notes on the docs page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/#comment-2506), you can use `wp_get_current_user()` from the [`plugins_loaded`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/) hook forward. `init` happens after `plugins_loaded`, according to [this resource](https://wp-kama.com/hooks/actions-order).